# Rxjs append string to an observable?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, angularfire2

I'm not really sure what the title of this post should be because I'm not sure what will accomplish it just yet.  I'm creating a simple ngx chart (bar graph) that displays the number of accounts in a given step.  I'm pulling the data from Firestore.  It's logging the number of accounts just fine but I need to also pass the step its corresponding to which is where I'm stuck.  The format of the data needs to be an array of name, value objects.  Here is my code.  Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

```
import { Account } from './../../../models/account.model';
import { ChartService } from './../../../services/chart.service';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/from';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/switchMap';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/combineAll';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-steps-chart',
  templateUrl: './steps-chart.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./steps-chart.component.css']
})
export class StepsChartComponent implements OnInit {
  steps = ['A', 'PA', 'PS', 'CI', 'CN'];
  steps$;
  chartData = [];
  count = 0;

  colorScheme = {
    domain: ['#03a9f4', '#009688', '#f29706', '#673ab7', '#f44336']
  };

  // options
  showXAxis = true;
  showYAxis = true;
  gradient = false;
  showLegend = true;
  showXAxisLabel = true;
  xAxisLabel = 'Steps';
  showYAxisLabel = true;
  yAxisLabel = 'Accounts';

  constructor(private chartService: ChartService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.steps$ = Observable.from(this.steps);

    this.chartService.getAccounts().switchMap(() => {
      const accounts$ = this.steps$.map(step => {
        return this.chartService.getAccountsByStep(step);
      });
      const combined$ = accounts$.combineAll();
      return combined$;
    }).map(accounts => {
      console.log(accounts);
      return accounts.map(a => {
        return {
          'name': step, // need to figure out how to get step
          'value': a.length
        };
      });
    })
    .subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data);
    });
  }

}
```

Comment: what is the goal of chartService.getAccounts()? you dont seem to use the data returned from it

Comment: I thought I needed it for triggering the function when a change is made to an account.  Is it not necessary in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `forkJoin` and reorganize like this:

```
// This is according to your comments in the code
const convertAccount = (account, step) => {
  return {
    name: step,
    value: account.length,
  };
};

// Gets the accounts for the given step and maps the result
// to the format we need for the chart.
const convertStep = step => this.chartService.getAccountsByStep(step)
  .map(accounts => accounts.map(account => convertAccount(account, step)));

Observable
  // Fire requests for all steps in parallel and wait for them
  // all to finish
  .forkJoin(...this.steps.map(convertStep))
  // Now we have an array of arrays, so flatten it out
  .map(([...data]) => data.reduce((a, b) => [...a, ...b], []))
  .subscribe(console.log)
```

I've removed the call to `this.chartService.getAccounts()` which doesn't appear to be doing anything.